# How to get jsonAray Response with no square brackets

Tags: android, json, android-volley

How do i get the json data using android volley when it has no square brackets. Just using jsonObjectRequest.

```
{"Code":"1","message":"true"}
```

Android volley code:

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(??)
                        code = obj.getString("Code");
                        message = obj.getString("message");
                    } catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Volley", error.toString());

                    }
                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(request);
```

Comment: try JSONObject request using volley

Comment: i can change the json to {"test":{"Code":"1","message":"true"}} if it works better

Comment: you are trying volley JSONArray request, try volley JSONObject  Request

Comment: Use JsonObjectRequest instead JsonArrayRequest

Comment: @BapusahebShinde must i change the code inside of the try catch as well?

Comment: make a string request for JSonObject or simple string

Comment: just change JsonArrayRequest to JsonObjectRequest, JSONArray to JSONObject, in your above code

Comment: Don't press down-vote . use `JsonObjectRequest `

Comment: for more detail refer : https://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

Comment: is it working now????

Comment: No its still not working, the code in the try catch is never run

Comment: @BapusahebShinde i edited the code, you see i don't know what to put in .getJSONObject(??)

Comment: dont use that: try code = response.getString("Code"); and message = response.getString("message");

Comment: it returns null, in post man it does return values